# Remix error when deploying

Tags: remix

Getting the following error when hitting deploy to Ropsten network

`creation of EventExample errored: call to plugin has timed out compilerMetadata - deployMetadataOf - {"from":"udapp","path":"compilerMetadata"}`

What does this mean? I am using Chrome, if it matters.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check that the address on your “account” is the same as in your udapp (i.e. if you use the dig. wallet metamask)
If it isn't, delete the connection from metamask to remix, click on the “connected” button - “disconnect this account” and try to connect it again. Another thing that worked for me is simply open remix in a new tab and re-established the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible fixes for the error:

1. Turn off your VPN if your're using one.
2. Refresh the remix page
3. Open Remix in new tab and reconnect.
4. Restart your browser (this may be common with chrome and brave browsers) and redeploy your contract.
5. Delete the connection from metamask to remix, and try to connect it again.
6. Try clearing the browser cache (ctrl + shift + delete). Make sure to save your work somewhere else as clearing the browser will delete the copy of your work.

In normal circumstances, the above-proposed solutions would work and you can get your work going. However, should the problem persist, change your browser and reload remix there.

or just restart your PC